# copy all xml node without prefix

Tags: xml, prefix

i need to copy a complete xml that contains prefix without prefix
i tried a couple of solution using exclude-result-prefixes but with no success

i used the below xslt

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:ns2="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/currencycode/54217:2001" xmlns:ns7="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/codelists" xmlns:ns1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/qualifieddatatypes/1.1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/languagecode/5639:1988" xmlns:ns4="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/unitcode/66411:2001" xmlns:ns6="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/IANAMIMEMediaTypes:2003" xmlns:ns5="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/unqualifieddatatypes/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="copy" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()" mode="copy">
      <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the source

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ns0:AcknowledgePurchaseOrder releaseID="" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" languageCode="en-US" xmlns:ns0="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" xmlns:ns2="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/currencycode/54217:2001" xmlns:ns7="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/codelists" xmlns:ns1="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/qualifieddatatypes/1.1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/languagecode/5639:1988" xmlns:ns4="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/unitcode/66411:2001" xmlns:ns6="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/IANAMIMEMediaTypes:2003" xmlns:ns5="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9/unqualifieddatatypes/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns0:ApplicationArea>
    <ns0:Sender>
                     <ns0:LogicalID>SEC</ns0:LogicalID>
            </ns0:Sender>
            <ns0:CreationDateTime>2016-06-15</ns0:CreationDateTime>
    </ns0:ApplicationArea>
    <ns0:DataArea>
            <ns0:Acknowledge>
                     <ns0:ResponseCriteria>
                             <ns0:ResponseExpression actionCode="update"/>
                     </ns0:ResponseCriteria>
            </ns0:Acknowledge>
            <ns0:PurchaseOrder>
                     <ns0:PurchaseOrderHeader>
                             <ns0:DocumentID xsi:type="ns0:ItemIDType">
                                      <ns0:ID>6286952</ns0:ID>
                             </ns0:DocumentID>
                             <ns0:Attachment inline="false"/>
                             <ns0:CustomerParty>
                                      <ns0:PartyIDs>
                                              <ns0:ID>692627</ns0:ID>
                                      </ns0:PartyIDs>
                             </ns0:CustomerParty>
                             <ns0:SupplierParty>
                                      <ns0:PartyIDs>
                                              <ns0:ID>SEC</ns0:ID>
                                      </ns0:PartyIDs>
                             </ns0:SupplierParty>
                     </ns0:PurchaseOrderHeader>
                     <ns0:PurchaseOrderLine>
                             <ns0:LineNumber>1</ns0:LineNumber>
                             <ns0:DocumentReference type="PurchaseOrder">
                                      <ns0:DocumentID xsi:type="ns0:ItemIDType">
                                              <ns0:ID>310924</ns0:ID>
                                      </ns0:DocumentID>
                             </ns0:DocumentReference>
                             <ns0:Attachment inline="false"/>
                             <ns0:Item>
                                      <ns0:CustomerItemID>
                                              <ns0:ID>02898347</ns0:ID>
                                      </ns0:CustomerItemID>
                             </ns0:Item>
                             <ns0:Quantity>30</ns0:Quantity>
                             <ns0:UnitPrice>
                                      <ns0:Amount currencyID="SEK">522.03</ns0:Amount>
                                      <ns0:PerQuantity>1</ns0:PerQuantity>
                             </ns0:UnitPrice>
                             <ns0:DrawingAttachment xsi:type="ns0:OpenAttachmentType" inline="false"/>
                             <ns0:PromisedDeliveryDateTime>2016-08-01</ns0:PromisedDeliveryDateTime>
                             <ns0:PurchaseOrderSubLine>
                                      <ns0:Attachment inline="false"/>
                             </ns0:PurchaseOrderSubLine>
                             <ns0:PurchaseOrderSchedule>
                                      <ns0:Attachment inline="false"/>
                             </ns0:PurchaseOrderSchedule>
                     </ns0:PurchaseOrderLine>
            </ns0:PurchaseOrder>
    </ns0:DataArea>
    </ns0:AcknowledgePurchaseOrder>
```

i would remove all ns0: from all the nodes

Comment: Do you want to retain the namespace membership of those nodes?

Comment: my goal is to have everything as it is except the ns0 in front of the tag

Comment: Tags mean namespaces: to perform a transform for this you need to work in terms of namespaces. To remove the `ns0` tag you'll need to remove elements from the `"http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9` namespace. Doing that in any XML-namespace aware tool (like XSLT) means some effort. In this case you'll need to use `xsl:element` to construct a new element name from the input document element's local name (you can use XPath's `local-name` for that).

Comment: thank you Richard, i tried that as well but it didn't work, do you have an example how to build it? thank you

Comment: The transform in the question copies the namespace: it will just retain the namespace tag. You need to create elements not in their source namespace.

Comment: how can i do that. do you have a short example? thank you

Comment: No short examples and no time to create one. But in your code 1. don't set the namespace of the new element, 2. use `local-name` not `name` to get its name.

Comment: done and it's working, thank you